# Cloning mongoose document property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

so I have a mongoose document like this:

```
dbArticle = {
  bundle:  {
    articles: [
      {
        article: 'a',
        quantity: 3
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Then I want to make a copy of the `bundle` property, and then change the `dbArticle` document:

```
const oldBundle = dbArticle.bundle;

dbArticle.bundle = {
    articles: [
      {
        article: 'b',
        quantity: 50
      }
    ]
  };
```

But for some reason, the `oldBundle` also changes, and I know about object references, but I tried this in repl.it and `oldBundle` should not change.

Is there something special with mongoose documents I'm not aware of?

Comment: I solved it with `oldBundle = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dbArticle.bundle)); `

But I am still confused as to how did that happened when I think it's not supposed to, with the way object references work.

Comment: Is there a mongoose/mongodb "_id" property associated with the document? If you remove that and save the document, mongo should see that as a new document and do a fresh insert.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that is not the issue, I wanted to save the "old state" of the document on a variable because I wanted to edit the document, but when I edited the document the "old state" variable also changed, and the way references work with objects that should not that happened, so I want to know what's so special with a mongoose document